# can we config the screen orientation for particular screen in React Native?

Tags: react-native, orientation, fullscreen, screen-orientation

I am new to react Native.  am stuck in a issue, is it possible to lock a Particular screen in Landscape in react-native ? in other words can we config the screen orientation for particular screen ?

Help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-native-orientation` or `react-native-orientation-locker`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker

React native orientation provided following API which help to achieve screen orientation

```
Orientation.lockToPortrait()
Orientation.lockToLandscape()
Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft()
Orientation.lockToLandscapeRight()
Orientation.unlockAllOrientations()
Orientation.getOrientation((err, orientation) => {})
Orientation.getSpecificOrientation((err, specificOrientation) => {})
```

Please check following code snippet

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation'

componentDidMount() {
   Orientation.unlockAllOrientations();
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   Orientation.lockToPortrait();
}
```

Comment: Thank you , for the answer, what if it is  a functional component, will it work? can i use use effect for this

Comment: Yes you can use useEffect as a life cycle method. It is also working with functional components.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried both packages.
`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker`
Both the packages work fine in android but I am getting the issue in ios devices it does not lock the orientation to landscape.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31705428)